# Tensorflow Keras custom metrics error on update_state()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow1.15

### Context

Using TF 1.15 with `tf.Estimator` interface to train and evaluate models. Trying to write a custom TF metric, using [`tf.keras.metric.Metric`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric) for that.

### Problem

I wrote a custom metric and included that in the `eval_metrics_ops` (example below). If I define an estimator with the metrics, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: Please call update_state(...) on the "<metric_name>" metric
```

The wording of the error looks clear (I have to call `update_state()`) but I am not sure where do I call `update_state()` on the metric (not sure if I even should call). Not a minimal example, but this is a demo metric I wrote.

```
class MyMetric(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name="my_metric", **kwargs):
        super(MyMetric, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        self.true_samples = tf.reduce_sum(y_true)
    
    def result(self):
        return self.true_samples
```

Creating a `dict` where metric name is the key and the metric instance is the value. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) is where it mentions how to create a `dict` for `eval_metrics_ops`.

```
metrics_ops = {"my_metric": MyMetric()}`. # The TensorFlow 1.15 documentation does not say we have to call `update_state(....) anywhere.`
estimator_spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, model.loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics_ops)
```

Any idea how I can get rid of that error?

Comment: Is it like this cannot be used with `tf.Estimator` interface? I have to use `Keras` interface `model.compile()` and `model.fit()`?

Comment: I don't think that is the case because `eval_metrics_ops` accepts an instance of `Metric` class.